# searching a csv and printing a line

Tags: python, csv

Trying to create a train booking system.
Having trouble searching my csv and printing that certain line.

The user already has there id number,and the csv is is set out like

This is what I have so far:

Comment: Just FYI, the built-in [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module will do most of the CSV parsing for you.

Comment: ``if id in line:`` would work but is not precise enough as ``id = 1`` would match all lines with ``1`` in it. You need to pull out the ``id`` column which doesn't seem to be in your dataset anyway.!

Answer (score 2):

You are matching the entire line against the ID. You need to split out the first field and check that:

```
def buySeat():
    id = raw_input("please enter your ID")

for line in open("customers.csv"):
    if line.split(',')[0] == id:
        print line
    else:
        print "sorry cant find you"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the built-in CSV module. It will make things easier to manage as your requirements change.

```
import csv

id = raw_input("please enter your ID")

ID_INDEX = 0

with open('customers.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in csvReader:
        # Ignore the column names on the first line.
        if row[ID_INDEX] != 'counter':
            if row[ID_INDEX] == id:
                print ' '.join(row)
            else:
                print 'sorry cant find you'
```